# Sequelize association with one table "hasMany" other tables

Tags: sequelize.js

What is the best way to associate the same table to many tables. I have 3 tables in mysql database, Owners, Pets, Posts. Where Owners has many Pets and also Owners has many posts. When I make the association in the Posts and Pets model as follows

```
Posts.associate = function(models) {
    Posts.belongsTo(models.Owners, {
        foreignKey: {
            allowNull: false
        }
    });
};
Pets.associate = function(models) {
    Pets.belongsTo(models.Owners, {
        foreignKey: {
            allowNull: false
        }
    });
};
```

And in the Owners model I tried to make the association, has many, for both like this:

```
Owners.associate = function(models) {
    Owners.hasMany(models.Pets, {
      onDelete: "cascade"
    });
};
Owners.associate = function(models) {
    Owners.hasMany(models.Posts, {
      onDelete: "cascade"
    });
};
```

but I keep on getting errors that either one of the tables in not associated to the Owners table. Is there a better way that makes this association work?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use hasMany on the Owners model, is not necessary to use belongsTo on the other models. When you use the hasMany it create the OwnerId on the target model, I recommend to use `as` so you can recognize
the key if you need to do an Include on queries . Also you just define once the associate function:

```
Owners.associate = function(models) {
  Owners.hasMany(models.Pets, {
    as: 'OwnerPets',
    onDelete: "cascade"
  });
  Owners.hasMany(models.Posts, {
    as: 'OwnerPosts',
    onDelete: "cascade"
  });
};
```